# Usage of Popup model and Export Feature in at data table

Tags: angular

use the user details mat data table.
Clicking upon column “Click here”, open the popup and show all the Employees/Department under that user.
Add an Export button and the excel file/csv file should get downloaded with the data.
angular 14 + version I'm using need a quick solution

columns would be

id, name, email,phone,company and under action column click here button with modal popup open and display all employees/ departments.

Also on clicking on any row a modal or diff component should open nd display additional information along with name, email,phone,company + address & website.

thank you all in advance.

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width py-2">
    <input class="mt-1"
           matInput
           (keyup)="applyFilter($event)"
           placeholder="Search"
           #input
    />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-card-header>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort
           #empTbSort="matSort">
      <!-- <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header >{{ column }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let emp">{{ emp[column] }}</td>
      </ng-container> -->

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header >No.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > email </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > phone </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phone}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > company </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.company}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> actions </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let actions">
          <button mat-button>Click here</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Role Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.role}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef ="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr (click)="editUser(emprow)" mat-row *matRowDef="let emprow; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

    </table>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

first You need to install package for XLSX like

> import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

and SaveAs package like

> import saveAs from 'file-saver';

now create the export method

```
  exportDataToExcel(): void {
   const formattedData = this.rowData.map((entry: any) => ({
      'ID': entry.id,
      'NAME': entry.name,
      'EMAIL': entry.email,
      'PHONE': entry.phone,
      'COMPANY': entry.company,
    }));

    // Create a new Excel workbook
        const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(formattedData);
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Sheet1');

      // Generate Excel file binary
        const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });


       // Save the file using FileSaver.js
        const filename = 'data_export.xlsx';
        const blob = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        saveAs(blob, filename);
      }
```

Now add the click event on column button.

```
 <a href="javascript:void()" (click)="exportDataToExcel()"><i class="fa fa-upload" title="Download as Excel"
            style=" float: right;margin: 3px;font-size: larger;"> </i></a>
```